# What is the different between upper bound wild cards with bound type parameters?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Both are using as restriction mechanisms and java document say that upper bound wild card will allow all the sub classes as variables while bound type parameters only accept declared class reference variables only.

My question is. for example if we take `Number` super class and declared it as a bound type parameters usually it will accept all the sub class variables too in practical scenario regardless of the subclass type. So why the wild cards?

Comment: Most people familiar with the subject can probably answer without any additional information but for the other people it would be nice to include examples where you use the different bounds and generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation `The term List<Number> is more restrictive than List<? extends Number> because the former matches a list of type Number only, whereas the latter matches a list of type Number or any of its subclasses.`

[upperBounded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

Consider this example

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Sample {

    public static double sumOfList(List<? extends Number> list) {
        double s = 0.0;
        for (Number n : list)
            s += n.doubleValue();
        return s;   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> ld = Arrays.asList(1.2, 2.3, 3.5);
        System.out.println("sum = " + sumOfList(ld));
    }

}
```

Above works fine as expected but if you change this line to `public static double sumOfList(List<Number> list) {`

then this line will complain

`System.out.println("sum = " + sumOfList(ld));` that change it to Number i.e. `List<Number> ld` or change

or change sub to `public static double sumOfList(List<Double> list) {`